# How to change the value of property using reducer function

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, reduce

I wanted to change the value of sample based on the length of validators in the below given

Original:

```
object1 = {test1:{sample: ["0"], validators: {length: 2}},
    test2: {sample: ["1"], validators: {length: 1}}}
```

Expected Result:

```
object1 = {test1:{sample: ["0", "1"], validators: {length: 2}},
test2: {sample: ["0"], validators: {length: 1}}}
```

Code:

```
    Object.keys(object1).reduce((acc.test) => ({
        ...acc, 
        [test]:{
           ...test,
           sample:Array(validators.length).fill(null).map((_, i) => i.toString)
        }
    }, {}));
```

Comment: no sure if this is what you wanted but check it out:  Object.keys(object1).reduce((acc) => {
              console.log(acc);
              console.log(object1[acc]);
              object1[acc].sample=Array(object1[acc].validators.length).fill(null).map((_, i) => i.toString());
              }
              );
   console.log(object1);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `map`:

```js
Object.keys(object1)
  .map(el => ({
    ...object1[el],
    sample: Array(object1[el].validators.length).fill(null).map((_, i) => i.toString())
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [validator]: {

              validations: Array(validators.length)

                .fill(null)

                .map((_, i) => i.toString()),

              validators,

            }
```